# python regex transpose capture group into another regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have:

```
regex1 = 'CCbl([a-z]{2})la-12([0-9])4'
inputstring = 'CCblabla-1234'
regex2_to_get_substituted = 'fof([a-z]{2})in(.)ha'

desired output = 'fofabin3ha'
```

Basically I want to get result of the capture groups from `regex1` and transpose them into the same positions of nth capture groups in `regex2` as a substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need a template for your desired output:

```py
import re

regex1 = r"CCbl([a-z]{2})la-12([0-9])4"
string = "CCblabla-1234"
template = "fof{}in{}ha"

groups = re.search(regex1, string).groups()
print(template.format(*groups))   # fofabin3ha
```

Those `{}`s in template will be substituted with the values of the `.groups()`.

---

After discussion in comments:

```py
import re

regex1 = r"CCbl([a-z]{2})la-12([0-9])4"
regex2 = r"fof([a-z]{2})in(.)ha"
string = "CCblabla-1234"

groups = re.search(regex1, string).groups()
print(re.sub(r"\(.*?\)", "{}", regex2).format(*groups))  # fofabin3ha
```

This converts the `regex2` groups into `{}` so that you can fill them later with the `.groups()` of `regex1`.

Comment: problem is this edits regex2 which i can't do

Comment: @tooptoop4 How do you want to edit it? Or let's ask the question this way, what is the problem with this solution? I think I don't get you.

Comment: regex2_to_get_substituted = 'fof([a-z]{2})in(.)ha' this is an existing value that i use for other things, but you are not using it, you have instead introduced a new {} value which is an extra thing i don't want to maintain

Comment: @tooptoop4 Check the updated answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: perfect! i accepted

Comment: @tooptoop4 Glad you find it useful.